# Java: resume Download in URLConnection

Tags: java, resume, urlconnection

I wrote a program that downloads some files from some servers.
Currently program works properly.
But I want to add resume support to it.
I'm doing it like this But the result file is corrupted:

```
....

File fcheck=new File(SaveDir+"/"+filename);
if(resumebox.isSelected() && fcheck.exists()){
    connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "Bytes="+(fcheck.length())+"-");
}

connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);

BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream (connection.getInputStream()); 

pbar.setIndeterminate(false);
pbar.setStringPainted(true);

java.io.FileOutputStream fos ;
if(resumebox.isSelected()){
    if(fcheck.exists()){
        if(connection.getHeaderField("Accept-Ranges").equals("bytes")){
            fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream(SaveDir+"/"+filename,true);
        }else{
            fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream(SaveDir+"/"+filename);
        }
    }else{
        fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream(SaveDir+"/"+filename);
    }
}else{
    fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream(SaveDir+"/"+filename);
}

....
```

I'm Testing it on a server that I know supports resume.
I downloaded some bytes.(72720)
Then Tried to resume it.
Then I opened file with a Hex editor , At offset 72720 the first Bytes are repeated:
Bytes 0-36: FLV.............«..........onMetaData
Bytes 72720-72756: FLV.............«..........onMetaData
It Starts download from the begining!
While when I do it by wget it does correctly and responses by Content-Range field!
Server responses with "302 FOUND" and a "206 Partial Content" in wget log.
Can "302 FOUND" cause the problem?

What is the problem ?
Thanks.

Comment: The other problem is that you've an unnecessarily deep nested if/else block. Make use of the `&&` operator. I.e. `if (a && b && c) { fos = new FOS(name, true); } else { fos = new FOS(name); }`. That's it. DRY.

Comment: I summarized code! in those if else blocks I'm rising some messages so it should be as it is. but thank you for your response.

Comment: The 302 shouldn't be a problem since HTTPUrlConnection follows redirects by default.  Unless you're turning redirects off explicitly, which I doubt since you're actually getting file contents

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + fcheck.length() + "-");
```

Lowercase the range specifier per the spec.  Also, if your partial file was 500 bytes, that means your byte range that you have is 0-499, and you want 500+.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. But It has another problem , I edited original post and added that problem.please check that out. thanks

Comment: You should consider using something like wireshark to make sure your request header is set properly.  You can try using addRequestProperty instead of setRequestProperty, though I would hope they both do the same thing.

Comment: Hi, I captured using wireshark. it is set: "Range: bytes=257177-"! but it starts from byte 0 again!

Comment: Interesting - try comparing the headers you have when issuing the wget and your code.  It looks right.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in `(fcheck.length() - 1)`: this should be `fcheck.length()`.