# How to download only part of a file with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, download

I am at work and have a need to download large files, 4gb+. I only actually need the first 20mb of these files, however. To conserve bandwidth and time, I would like to only download the first 20mb instead of the whole file. Because I am at work and using Windows 7, I cannot install new software or compile anything. I saw, in the link below, that someone attempts to do this using Java. Because I have access to a web browser, I am able to make applications with Javascript. Is there a way to accomplish downloading only part of a file using only Javascript?

[How do I download part of a file using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127104/how-do-i-download-part-of-a-file-using-java)

Answer (score 1):

You can send a [HTTP RANGE](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p5-range-22#section-3) request. This has little to do with JavaScript apart from the fact that you may send the request via AJAX

Comment: hmm... This may not be the right route. Can you think of any other solution to my problem?

Comment: Well, "to download only part of a file", this is your best if not only chance. This may be tricky to achieve and requires correct server-side configuration/code to handle partial download properly.

Comment: Another way I can think of is if you handle it on server side entirely w/o RANGE request. What I mean is that you could send a request with parameters and those params would tell the server which part of what file you expect in response. Then server-side code can find the file, extract the desired part and send it back to the browser.

Comment: I don't have access to the server and it doesn't support range requests. :(