# download only first N bytes from file on web JAVA Android

Tags: java, android

I want download only first 3 bytes of file from web, but can't do that.

This method download all file

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(imageStream), 3);
```

as I get InputStream class always download all file..

Comment: Duplicate question - See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127104/how-do-i-download-part-of-a-file-using-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes="+0+"-"+2);
        connection.connect();

        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        line = r.readLine();
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, line);
```

Answer (score 0):

BufferedReaderis handy if you are trying to read characters. 
For example:
char[] charBuff = new charBuff[n];
 new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream)).read(charBuff,0,n);
This Wii read n bytes from the input stream and will store them in the char array.

If you just want to read bytes and store them in a byte array try using this:
byte[] byteBuff= new byteBuff[n];
new BufferedInputStream(input stream).read(byteBuff,0,n);