# Download, with java, a large file throughtout a size limiting firewall.

Tags: java, download, size, firewall

Well, I suppose that the title explains it quite well. But I think I'd rather explain the problem: I'm at work, and sometimes i need to download a file which is larger than the 26 mg limit firewall.

I am quite aware on how to download a file, using java or c#.
What i need to do is separating the file in smaller chunks, which is fine, but how would be done?

Do I need to, have to or can, "`masquerade`" the file size, so it can be firewall approvable?

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

thank

As sanjay had asked me, the access is made through a webserver.

Comment: What protocol does the server expose to you? Regular sockets? A web server? Also, please be aware that unless the file itself is fragmented, chunk support depends a lot on the server implementation. Any more specifics would help.

Comment: How about using a Download Manager such as: http://www.speedbit.com/ you can even find an open source one like: http://dfast.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Assuming the file is for a work related purpose, have you talked to the Network team to either increase your download permission on the firewall, or to get them to download it for you so you can access it from inside the firewall?

Comment: @rossum, if I could ask them for it, then I would not need to ask for the hints on how to make the code, right? The file is work, is just too problematic to ask anything to our infrastructure dep.

Comment: You need to know how they block it first. Is this http files? FTP? msn file transfer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Chunking' from the client perspective is done through http resume.
See the answer to this question:
[Java: resume Download in URLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414438/java-resume-download-in-urlconnection)

Comment: Perfect! `connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes="+fcheck.length()+"-");` is exactly what I wanted. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I did not test it before, the web proxy does not measure the traffic, as I had thought. It does only read the header...

Comment: so, in order to be able to surpass the proxy limitations, I would've to change the response header in a some sort of proxy of my own, outside my work network.

Comment: and implement a download "chunker"

Comment: You might be better off seeing if the network admins can put an exclusion on the address of the url that you're trying to access.