# Downloading only a small part of an HTML document

Tags: android, html, http, download

I've thought about implementing an Android application that will download data from a third-party website. The website contains multiple pages, each one containing only about 200 bytes of useful data and around 20 Kbytes of data that I don't want to use. Is there any way to download only that part of a document? Or somehow filter the data to minimize the amount of downloaded information? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this SO-post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414438/java-resume-download-in-urlconnection

Comment: @dacwe, I'm not talking about resuming download, I want to download only a part of an HTML document.

Comment: The accepted answer to that other question tells you exactly how to download a specified range of a document, which is what you are asking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `Range` HTTP request header, with which you can specify a start and end *inclusive byte* address within the resource.

```
Range: bytes=0-99
```

will retrieve the first *100 bytes*, as the header specifies the region from the first byte (at offset zero) up to and including the 100th byte (at offset 99). Likewise

```
Range: bytes=0-0
```

will retrieve the first byte.

---

Get it working first with the BBC web site, that I know honours the `Range` header.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $req = HTTP::Request->new('GET', 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/');
$req->header('Range', 'bytes=0-13');
my $resp = $ua->request($req);

print $resp->decoded_content;
```

This returns the first fourteen bytes of the page `<!DOCTYPE html`.

Then plug in our own site. If it still gives you the whole site then you're out of lukc and you can't restict what's returned I'm afraid.

---

It wouldn't be fair to leave you with just a Perl version. Here's the Java

```java
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpGet req = new HttpGet("http://www.bbc.co.uk/");
req.setHeader("Range", "bytes=0-13");
HttpResponse resp = client.execute(req);
HttpEntity ent = resp.getEntity();
String content = EntityUtils.toString(ent);

System.out.println(resp.getStatusLine());
System.out.println(ent.getContentLength());
System.out.println(content);
```

which outputs

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
14
<!DOCTYPE html
```

showing that just 14 bytes have been read. Plug your URL into this and see if it behaves.

Comment: +1, just note that servers don't always honour the range requests.

Comment: Yes dacwe, but then there is no way to retrieve anything but the entire resource.

Comment: @borodin, Tried the following code: 
HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
  getRequest.addHeader("Range", "bytes=0-199");
And it doesn't seem to work. Still downloads the whole page.

Comment: You may have a site that ignores the `Range` header. I've updated my answer to give you something to test.

Comment: I've added a Java version of my quick Perl test.

Answer (score 0):

If the Sites are always very similar you can use `skip(n)`-Method of `InputStream` to skip n bytes.

Comment: You still "download" the data - then you skip it.