# How i reset an URL connection

Tags: java

I use URL connection to download stream in the Internet. But after i reset the modem, i can't continue download this stream caz it error: Connection reset. How i solve it?
Here is my code:

```
URL url = new URL(_URL);
HttpURLConnection hUC = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
hUC.connect();
while (true) {
    if ((_data.num = is.read(_data.b)) == -1) {
                    break;
                }

                //write to file
                fos.write(_data.b, 0, _data.num);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't - at least, not how you may be expecting.

Instead, you need to handle your exception, and determine how much data you've already read.  Once your Internet connection is re-established - assuming that the HTTP server you're downloading from supports requestable byte ranges - you can then set custom HTTP Headers on the request and re-download the remaining portions.  (This will require a new `HttpURLConnection`.)

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35 shows the related HTTP specifications involved to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit more complicated if you're looking for a "resume" type feature.

You would need to reissue the request once the internet comes back after a disconnect, and add a header to the request in order to resume the download at the byte number where you left off.
You need to set the Range property in the request header in order to specify how far in you're resuming. Then you would just continue to write to the "fos" object from there.

Check out this url: [Java: resume Download in URLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414438/java-resume-download-in-urlconnection)